# Is it possible to password protect a zip file created by Windows itself (without external tools?)

Tags: windows-7, zip, password-protection

I normally use a tool like WinZip, 7Zip, or WinRAR to create zip files but I'm on a Windows 7 system that doesn't have these tools installed (and I can't install new apps).

Outside of 3rd party tools like the above, can I create (or modify) a zip file in Windows 7 and request that it be password protected? (the files would contain sensitive information that I plan to transmit to another PC)*

e.g. the process I'm familiar with on Windows is to select the files, right click and choose: "Send to..." > "Compressed (zipped) folder" - but there doesn't seem to be any additional options.

* Note: I'm aware this isn't 100% secure, locked down mega encryption - just looking for "reasonable effort" to secure the data in transit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Windows does not provide this [feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Can-I-protect-files-or-folders-with-a-password).

Have you considered using a portable app? You can install the portable versions of [WinRAR](http://portableapps.com/node/10331) or [7Zip](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) to your USB, and use them to zip and password protect any file/folder you want. That way, you don't need to install anything to your windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

There is a portable version of 7zip.  No installation required.  You can run it off your thumb drive.

[Get it here](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable)
Or use portable PeaZip from the same site.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/), a Shareware file manager for Windows, which can be run off a thumb drive also. And to create such thumb drive version, all that's needed is to copy a Total Commander folder (with all its subfolders), from an existing Total Commander installation you have available somewhere (e.g. on another PC).

One, out of a zillion of its features, is handling ZIP files, which also includes an option to enter an *encryption key*, which is used to protect a ZIP file with a password (which has to be entered whenever such file is to be unzipped).

Comment: the Open Source clone [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) can handle it as well. Pack marked files with `Alt+F5` and then check `Encrypt`. It will then ask you for the password.

Comment: Is that a tatradog or a Pyrenean mountain dog next to you? :-)

Comment: @Dominique it is a Pyr ... actually it passed away at the age of about 12,5 y old. And what is more: since a few weeks I have adopted a 2,5 years old successor of it (it looks like a twin of it). Amazing / adorable dogs ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: I know exactly what you're talking about ... with that difference that mine is a tatra dog. 6.5 years old at this moment, and every evening I come home, he's waiting for me in the couch, proud as a sphinx, as if he's saying "Look at me, bossy, how good I am!" :-) :-) :-)